# Can a year have 364 days?

Tags: date, .net-4.0, comments

Here's a bit of fun.

If we peek at the dotnet source code, the following comment can be found at the [head of the file `TimeSpan.cs`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/timespan.cs#L22):

> ...while a year can contain 365 or 364 days

Should I be worried?

Comment: A comment in the .NET source code is the last thing I would worry about. I would be more worried if there was a bug in my code related to this.

Comment: [Give us our eleven days!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_%28New_Style%29_Act_1750#Subsequent_events) (Possibly apocryphal)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what the source code comment refers to, but there are some more exotic calendars where a year only has 364 days, e.g. a [leap week calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_week_calendar):

> A leap week calendar is a calendar system with a whole number of weeks every year, and with every year starting on the same weekday. Most leap week calendars are proposed reforms to the civil calendar, but some - such as the ISO week number calendar - are simply conveniences for specific purposes.
>
> The ISO calendar in question is a variation of the Gregorian calendar that is used (mainly) in government and business for fiscal years, as well as in timekeeping. In this system a year (ISO year) has 52 or 53 full weeks (364 or 371 days).

One advantage is the better divisibility. A year with 364 days can be divided into 13 equal months. Other calendars using such a system are according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform):

- [International Fixed Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar)
- [Pax Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Calendar)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps they were talking about the maximum day index in a year when the day index starts at zero?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should not be too worried. There are some years back in time with much less than 364 days! Basically, the crux is the change from Julian to Gregorian calendars, which happened at differing times at differing locales. In the US, the month of interest is Sep 1752,

```
jlouis@illithid:~$ cal sep 1752
   September 1752
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    1  2 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

since the US was part of the British Empire at that time, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption

for further explanation.

Aside: This is why you should generally not try to do your own date handling. It is pure pain to get all the intricacies correct.

Comment: This is the longer explanation of a comment to the question above, I've just realized.

Answer (score 2):

West Samoa crossed the dateline in 2011, skipping December 30th, going from December 29th directly to December 31st.

So technically they had a 364 day year.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps they meant 365 or 366 days? As far as I know 364 days in a year is not acceptable.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Additionally, it is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

No it can not. Maybe you should worry. Although the number of integer weeks x days per week = 52 x 7 = 364

Comment: In DateTime.cs ffs! I am worried!

Comment: I downvoted this because it starts with a completely false statement.